# What does protractorBy do?

Tags: protractor

I'm new to Protractor.  and I have been using "element(by.locatorName(''))" but I came across this "ProtractorBy".  Are they related to each other?  I found explanation in github, but I don't understand it.

https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/5.4.1/lib/locators.ts

```
export class ProtractorBy extends WebdriverBy {
  [key: string]: any;

  /**
   * Add a locator to this instance of ProtractorBy. This locator can then be
   * used with element(by.locatorName(args)).
   *
   * @view
   * <button ng-click="doAddition()">Go!</button>
   *
   * @example
   * // Add the custom locator.
   * by.addLocator('buttonTextSimple',
```

Comment: I think the answer is in the comments of the file you linked. I've never used it but just from reading the comments it looks like it can be used to add a custom locator if you needed one. For example, if `by.css()` or `by.id()` or any of the other built in locators don't work for what you need, you can create a custom one and use it like `element(by.myCustomLocator())`.

Comment: thank you for your explanation